# Importing classes works in console but not in browser

Tags: javascript, html, typescript

Whenever I use node to run `main.js` in the console, everything gets printed just fine. However, whenever I try running it through the browser (via an HTML file), nothing gets printed to the console.

However, when I comment out any references to `Vector.ts` in the `main.js` code, "Hello, World" gets printed. I believe it has something to do with the imports, but I am not sure - I am very new to web development in general.

Code:

> main.ts

```js
/// <reference path = "Vector.ts" />

import { Vector } from "./Vector"

class Startup {
    public static main(): number {
        console.log('Hello, World!!');

        //Test Vector classes
        let v = new Vector(1, 2);
        let w = new Vector(3, 4);
        console.log(v.dotProduct(w));
        
        return 0;
    }
}

Startup.main();
```

> Vector.ts

```js
export class Vector {
    
    constructor(private a: number, private b: number) {
        console.log("TEST");
    }

    dotProduct(v: Vector) :number {
        return this.a * v.a + this.b * v.b;
    }

}
```

> tsconfig.json

```js
{
    "compileOnSave": true,
    "compilerOptions": {
        "target": "es2015",
        "module": "umd",
        "sourceMap": true,
        "strict": true,
        "noImplicitReturns": true,
        "noUnusedParameters": true,
        "noUnusedLocals": true,
        "watch": true
    }
}
```

Comment: are you using a modern browser? and importing your js code via a script tag with `type="module"` attribute?

Comment: I am using the latest update of Chrome to run it. Also, when I did that, I get an error stating that "Access to script at file:///path/to/Vector.js" from origin 'null' has been blocked by CORS policy".

Answer (score 0):

Have you put js method call inside `document.onLoad()` block ?

I am not sure of your full scenario but sometimes it happens that the method is called before HTML is fully loaded. Maybe you can try putting the js function call code `(Startup.main() )` inside `document.onLoad()` block and see.

Comment: It's exhibiting some weird behavior. When I call main() in the onLoad block, Hello World! gets printed whenever I comment out every line referencing Vector or its instances. However, when I leave the imports in, I get an error stating that the main method is not defined. I have a feeling that TypeScript isn't importing correctly, but I am not knowledgeable enough to know why.